# Contract ERC20 creation "pending"

Tags: contract-deployment, pending-transactions

I have created a new ERC20 contract using this generator  https://vittominacori.github.io/erc20-generator/

The status is "pending" , 21 hours at this time. Some explanation?

Previously, I tried it on Ropsten, with success.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the transaction hash in plaintext - it's impossible to get from the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you deployed it on the Main Net using MetaMask.

Probably the gas limit of the transaction was too low.

Otherwise the gas price was to low.

Please send a screenshot of your MetaMask transactions, in case above didn't fix it.

Comment: Please mark as answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was insufficient ETH.